# Macbook is waking up from sleep while on wifi with iMac

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I have an Macbook Pro 13" 2018 as my portable/home computer and iMac in the office as workstation. When I bring the Macbook to the office and it connects to office wifi, it keeps waking up in the bag, draining the battery.

I tried to reinstall macOS, everything was ok until I signed in with my Apple ID, so I suppose it's due to handoff/continuity (only thing I have installed now is iStat menus and I'm signed to iCloud, nothing else, clean OS.)

I can lose almost full battery in one day in sleep if I don't turn off wifi and also the Macbook gets very hot and it even reboots itself because of the high temperature.

[image: cpu usage graph]

I use macOS 10.15.2 on both computers.

How can I prevent this and still have handoff/continuity enabled?

Comment: Periodic wake ups are normal with [Power Nap](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204032).  Is it staying awake and not going back to sleep?

Comment: [Something is definitely up here](https://twitter.com/chockenberry/status/1217501543886311424) @Allan too many people are getting massive [power drains in closed clamshell](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379661/),  the nap settings are the same afaik but the energy expended has ballooned. I [doubt it’s just Catalina](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378258/) but it could be EFI issued when Catalina happens and doesn’t roll back like this report.

Comment: I agree @bmike - someone was commenting to me recently that they keep forgetting to charge their MBP because it's always dead - now I'm thinking otherwise and confirming my thoughts that upgrading to Catalina is not a wise idea for production machines at this point.  I'm just really interested in this question and answer.

Comment: @Allan both are turned off for battery and also power adapter. As you can see from the chart, it's waking up and going to sleep OK, but too often.

Well I don't have problems like others, it's doing only when my MBP and iMac are on same wifi so I think it has something with continuity. I can have MBP at home for whole day and loose 1%.

Answer (score 1):

Power Management is the culprit.

You should use the pmset command to see what power management has been doing.  In Terminal, the basic command is

```
pmset -g log
```

But that gives you all the power management events since last boot time.  You can reduce this with judicious use of grep.  I have used both of these (with similar results):

```
pmset -g log | grep -e "Wake from" -e "DarkWake" -e "due"
pmset -g log | egrep "\b(Sleep|Wake*|DarkWake|Start)\s{2,}"
```

Power Management has about 20 settings that can be changed by an admin user.  To view the settings (they will be different when on battery and power):

```
pmset -g
```

For my issue, which looks similar to yours, I changed the *tcpkeepalive* setting.  With this enabled (value = 1), the MacBook will frequently wake up due to network events.

To change turn off tcpkeepalive use the Terminal command:

```
sudo pmset -b tcpkeepalive 0
```

The -b is to set for when running on battery.

I have also tweaked a few other settings like *standbydelayhigh*, but this is purely tweaking.

This is based on my experience with a MacBook which would lose too much (I thought) battery whilst closed overnight.

You may find these two links helpful:
[How to Fix macOS Mojave Battery Draining Issue](https://appletoolbox.com/how-to-fix-macos-mojave-battery-draining-issue/) and 
[man pmset](https://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/pmset.html).

Note that I have not changed *hibernatemode* from the default value of 3.  Many (including the linked article) discuss changing it to 25 which I do not recommend with recent (last 4 years) hardware and macOS version.