# Macbook pro fan going on while sleeping

Tags: sleep-wake, energy

I bought a 2019 15" this month (Jan 2020).
Stats:

```
Processor: 2.6 ghz 6-core i7
Memory: 16gb 2400 MHz DDR4
Graphics: Radeon Pro 555x
```

It throttles randomly even when I'm not doing anything tasking. I have attached a screenshot of what my activity monitor might look like at any given moment.[image: Typical laptop activity]

Cpu (edit):
[image]

This evening, while it was sleeping it was throttling and thats why I am worried. Any ideas what could be causing this? Could it be because Hyper is running and it uses graphics card?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! you may take some time to read [tour] while your question gets answers. **1** Could you add CPU tab too ? **2** Also, did you try [SMC reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) "*Fans and other thermal-management features*"?  **3** Please look up similar questions on the site using search, and the sidebar. @uessien

Comment: @ankii I have added a screen of the cpu. I haven't tried SMC reset yet. It doesn't do this all the time, but I have noticed it more when I have Hyper open.

I did a search before I posted this topic.

Comment: There are a lot of similar issues to this; see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379890/macbook-is-waking-up-from-sleep-while-on-wifi-with-imac - we're monitoring this because this seem to be a larger issue.